# Iterator hierarchy

Tags: oop, class, inheritance

Which inheritance makes more sense :

```
class SequentialIterator{ 
  SequentialIterator next(); 
};
class RandomAccessIterator : public SequentialIterator{
  RandomAccessIterator shift( int del );
};
```

or

```
class RandomAccessIterator {
  RandomAccessIterator shift( int del );
};
class SequentialIterator : public RandomAccessIterator{ 
  SequentialIterator next(); 
};
```

If I say "the derived class gives more complicated functionality than the base class" (first of all does this statement even make sense here), which is the more basic operation : *next* or *shift*?

EDIT : I'm actually designing interfaces for number sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at this from the wrong direction. In your first code-snippet, you essentially have three methods:

```
SequentialIterator.next()
RandomAccessIterator.next() // same as SequentialIterator.next()
RandomAccessIterator.shift(int)
```

In your second, you also have three methods, but they're not the same ones:

```
RandomAccessIterator.shift(int)
SequentialIterator.shift(int) // same as RandomAccessIterator.shift(int)
SequentialIterator.next()
```

Looked at in this way, I think it should be clear that only the first version makes sense: a `RandomAccessIterator` class can reasonably offer a `next()` method, but a `SequentialIterator` class cannot reasonably offer a `shift(int)` method.

(This is assuming, of course, that there's some reason to have one of them inherit from the other to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe shift is more basic as next seems like a specific kind of shift. But it's a bit odd to think that a SequentialIterator would derive from a RandomIterator and vice versa.

I would recommend deriving both from Iterator and then putting some of the common functionality into a IteratorHelper class.